# Flex home doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, apache-flex

Am trying to execute"ant" build using Jenkins groovy script, but build is failing because of FLEX_HOME path in the Jenkins server. I have the flex related files in bit bucket and gave the path, still not working.

Comment: Can you give us your Jenkins logging output and some more insight on that groovy script?

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed. Corrected the path to refer files in bit bucket.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by the OP (see comment)